# How do I convert my machine learning model in a rest node api

Tags: machine-learning

This is my code, how can I convert the model into a node rest api. I have created the traning set and saved the model. Can anyone help me with the api part I have tried but was not successful.

```
training = []

output = []
```

## create an empty array for our output

```
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
```

## training set, bag of words for each sentence

```
for doc in documents:

    # initialize our bag of words

    bag = []

    # list of tokenized words for the pattern

    pattern_words = doc[0]

    # stem each word

    pattern_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]

    # create our bag of words array

    for w in words:

        bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)



    # output is a '0' for each tag and '1' for current tag

    output_row = list(output_empty)

    output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1



    training.append([bag, output_row])



# shuffle our features and turn into np.array

random.shuffle(training)training = []

output = []

# create an empty array for our output

output_empty = [0] * len(classes)



# training set, bag of words for each sentence

for doc in documents:

    # initialize our bag of words

    bag = []

    # list of tokenized words for the pattern

    pattern_words = doc[0]

    # stem each word

    pattern_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]

    # create our bag of words array

    for w in words:

        bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)



    # output is a '0' for each tag and '1' for current tag

    output_row = list(output_empty)

    output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1



    training.append([bag, output_row])



# shuffle our features and turn into np.array

random.shuffle(training)

training = np.array(training)



# create train and test lists

train_x = list(training[:,0])

train_y = list(training[:,1])

training = np.array(training)



# create train and test lists

train_x = list(training[:,0])

train_y = list(training[:,1])

tf.reset_default_graph()

# Build neural network

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])

net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)

net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)

net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')

net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

## Define model and setup tensorboard

```
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')

# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)

model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=4000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
```

## saving the model

```
model.save('model.tflearn')

# save all of our data structures
import pickle
pickle.dump( {'words':words, 'classes':classes, 'train_x':train_x, 'train_y':train_y}, open( "training_data", "wb" ) )

import pickle

data = pickle.load( open( "training_data", "rb" ) )

words = data['words']

classes = data['classes']

train_x = data['train_x']

train_y = data['train_y']



# import our chat-bot intents file

import json

with open('D:\\android\\ad.json') as json_data:

    intents = json.load(json_data)

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    

    # tokenize the pattern

    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

    # stem each word

    sentence_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words]

    return sentence_words



# return bag of words array: 0 or 1 for each word in the bag that exists in the sentence

def bow(sentence, words, show_details=False):

    # tokenize the pattern

    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)

    # bag of words

    bag = [0]*len(words)  

    for s in sentence_words:

        for i,w in enumerate(words):

            if w == s: 

                bag[i] = 1

                if show_details:

                    print ("found in bag: %s" % w)



    return(np.array(bag))

ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
```

## classifying the inputs

```
def classify(sentence):

    # generate probabilities from the model

    results = model.predict([bow(sentence, words)])[0]

    # filter out predictions below a threshold

    results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD]

    # sort by strength of probability

    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    return_list = []

    for r in results:

        return_list.append((classes[r[0]], r[1]))

    # return tuple of intent and probability

    return return_list




def response(sentence, userID='123', show_details=False):

    results = classify(sentence)

    # if we have a classification then find the matching intent tag

    if results:

        # loop as long as there are matches to process

        while results:
            
            
                     
            for i in intents['intents']:
                

                # find a tag matching the first result

                if i['tag'] == results[0][0]:

                    # a random response from the intent

                    return print(random.choice(i['response']))
```

Comment: Please *tag* the question appropriately, in order to increase the chances of getting an answer (it is not actually about `machine-learning`...); `node.js` maybe?

Comment: Do you want to use python in your backend or you want JS or perhaps golang? If you use python - then it should not be difficult by adding flask and creating some api routes. For golang - I know it is possible because there is a Go wrapper for tensorflow. As for JS - I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this. You can use Server frameworks like Flask or Django. I will be presenting a simple example using flask : (note this is just an abstract prototype)

**Create a model class**

```
import libraries

class Model ():
    def __init__(self):
      self.model = load()

    def inference(self, inpts):
       return self.model.predict(inputs)
```

Note, this is just a prototype, the functions are implemented by you.

**Create a REST endpoint**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify 
from model import Model
app = Flask("__main__")
model = Model()

@app.route("/inference", methods =["POST"])
def inference():
   data = request.get_json()
   results = model.inference(data["inputs"])
   return jsonify( 
       {"result" : results }
   )
```

Then you can use **curl** to test the endpoint, and you can alse axios or fetch to send post request to the endpoint. **don't forget to add cors if you are trying on same domains**. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to Tflearn documentation, the library remains compatible with Tensorflow. 
Google released Tensorflow JS which works both as browser based and NodeJS Javascript libraries.

Tensorflow models can be loaded to Tensorflow.JS as described in the link:

https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-saved-model.html

For the reference; model needs to be converted to TF.JS format

-You need to install Tensorflow.JS to your Python environment first:

```
pip install tensorflowjs
```

-Convert an existing TensorFlow model to TensorFlow.js Web format

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
--input_format=tf_saved_model \
--output_node_names='Some/Model/Name' \
--saved_model_tags=serve \
/my/saved_model \
/my/web_model
```

Load the saved model in NodeJS environment:

```
const model = await tf.loadModel('file:///mypath/mymodel.json');
```

Comment: i am using python as my backend and integrating it to angular front end.